# Please help explain: 精神小伙 & 葬爱家族

Tags: meaning

I think maybe the  精神小伙 seems like bad luck and the other 葬爱家族 is like emo?

Here are some videos for context on the internet slang:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMJJoZ4i1KI    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Cj4GpSdfQ8    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmmtYesSvjE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the videos, 精神小伙 (energetic young man) and 葬爱家族 (Clan of love burier) are the descriptions of the two rap artists who are doing a rap battle

> [精神小伙](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%B2%BE%E7%A5%9E%E5%B0%8F%E4%BC%99): 原指收拾的十分利落，看起来充满活力、很有精神的小伙子。现在几乎特指看起来很社会的土味小伙子 -- originally refers to a very neat looking and energetic young man. Now almost specifically refers to **an earthy guy who looks very social**

> [葬爱家族](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%91%AC%E7%88%B1%E5%AE%B6%E6%97%8F/20155865): 网络词语，葬爱家族是《劲舞团》中传出来的“网络组织”，好多玩家以杀马特造型示人，造型夸张，喜欢斗舞，并组成一个群体接纳另一个她(他)。**现在大多指发型夸张，打扮狰狞且特立独行的反潮流的洗剪吹人士** (Nowadays, mostly refer to those who have exaggerated hairstyles and maverick anti-trend dresses)

Basically:

- 精神小伙 (Energetic young man) --> Earthy social young man
- 葬爱家族 (Clan of love burier) --> Anti-trend hair and fashion  style maverick